# Animate border in jQuery until selected element by sequent

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code, how can I add animation to borders properly so when use clicks on `a` the all previous borders get the `anime100` class after each other in a sequence?

It's now adding the `anime100` to all anime classes at the same time.

```js
$("a:eq( 1 )").on("click", function() {
  $('.anime:eq( 0 )').addClass('anime100');
});

$("a:eq( 2 )").on("click", function() {
  $('.anime:eq( 0 )').addClass('anime100');
  $('.anime:eq( 1 )').addClass('anime100');
});

$("a:eq( 3 )").on("click", function() {
  $('.anime:eq( 0 )').addClass('anime100');
  $('.anime:eq( 1 )').addClass('anime100');
  $('.anime:eq( 2 )').addClass('anime100');
});

$("a:eq( 4 )").on("click", function() {
  $('.anime:eq( 0 )').addClass('anime100');
  $('.anime:eq( 1 )').addClass('anime100');
  $('.anime:eq( 2 )').addClass('anime100');
  $('.anime:eq( 3 )').addClass('anime100');
});

$("a:eq( 5 )").on("click", function() {
  $('.anime:eq( 0 )').addClass('anime100');
  $('.anime:eq( 1 )').addClass('anime100');
  $('.anime:eq( 2 )').addClass('anime100');
  $('.anime:eq( 3 )').addClass('anime100');
  $('.anime:eq( 4 )').addClass('anime100');
});
```

```css
.anime {
  height: 10px;
  width: 0px;
  background: gold;
  transition: all 0.7s;
}

.anime100 {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="">
  <li>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="left"><a href="#">A</a></div>
      <div class="anime"></div>
    </div>

  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="left"><a href="#">B</a></div>
      <div class="anime"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="left"><a href="#">C</a></div>
      <div class="anime"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="left"><a href="#">D</a></div>
      <div class="anime"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="left"><a href="#">E</a></div>
      <div class="anime"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="left"><a href="#">F</a></div>
      <div class="anime"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could minify this code quite a bit doing something like the following by looping through your elements and using a combination of `.delay()`, `.queue()` and `.dequeue()`:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pqydpje4/2/)

```
var startEq = 0; // Start at 0 (first element)

$("a").on("click", function() {
  var maxEq = $('li').has(this).index(); // Current clicked element's parent index

  $('.anime').each(function(i) {

    if (startEq >= maxEq) {
      return; // Stop loop once current target is reached
    }

    $('.anime:eq(' + startEq + ')').delay(200 * i).queue(function() {
      $(this).addClass('anime100').dequeue();
    });

    startEq += 1; // Add 1 after each loop 
  });
});
```